# Xcode4 - Is there a key binding for block comments?

Tags: comments, xcode4, key-bindings

I'm new to Xcode4 and looking for a key binding that inserts block comments to methods and classes.

For Example a written function:

```
void test(int i) {};
```

I'd like to have an block comment to this:

```
/** test
*
* @param int i
* @return void
*/
void test(int i) {};
```

Comment: hi! Did you found the shortcut? thanks

Comment: Sorry but I still did not find it :(

Comment: ok, thanks, I hope in future xcode will have this feature..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a shortcut to make a block comment in XCode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212288/is-there-a-shortcut-to-make-a-block-comment-in-xcode)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>option</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd>

```
/// <#Description#>
///
/// - Parameter i: <#i description#>
func test(i: Int) {}
```